# Webcam not working after MacOS update to version 11.2.1

Tags: hardware, big-sur, facetime, webcam

I have a 16 inch MacBook Pro. The webcam on it was working fine before the update. But since the update, when I open FaceTime, it shows I guess what is the first frame, and that's it - there's no video feed from the webcam, just a dark, static image of the first frame:

[image]

Has anyone else faced this issue? And how do I fix it? I tried restarting the system a couple of times, but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the model of Mac and of the webcam, also if the webcam shows up in the system report.

Comment: Edited the question to include the model of the MacBook. However, I don't know what the model of the webcam is or how to check it, and also what or where to find the "system report". Anyway, the issue seems to have vanished somehow, and I've posted an answer just now detailing what I did.

Comment: Did you buy the webcam or is this the built-in camera? `About this Mac > System Report > Hardware`

Answer (score 0):

The webcam is working fine now. So, I want to note down what I did (although, it isn't much, and I'm not sure how or what exactly fixed the issue).

I stumbled across [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244115/macbook-webcam-only-shows-black-and-green-led-is-always-on?rq=1) post, asking a similar question. And I decided to follow along with the only answer in it. So, I shut down my mac, held down the `D` key, and switched on the mac. I kept holding the `D` key, and it booted a second time and went into recovery mode or something - it asked me to select a WiFi access point and enter its password. I got scared and clicked on the power button and restarted the system.

And that's it; when I open FaceTime now, it works fine. So, yeah, not sure what happened, but the issue seems to have been fixed somehow.

Comment: So, probably a restart fixed it...?